# Updating Sharepoint Excel from local Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sharepoint

We have multiple excel workbooks that get updated weekly, then we have to manually copy and paste from the local spreadsheet to the Sharepoint. Is there a simple way to automate this process? In the most basic way to ask this question is there a way if I change\enter something into cell A1 of the local Excel file how can I get cell A1 of the Sharepoint spreadsheet to reflect?

Comment: It depends on how the resulting workbook on SharePoint is structured and what level of access you have to that file. Using Power Query can help you load data from local workbooks to a workbook that is synced with SharePoint.

Comment: Okay so I found that if I open the SharePoint excel using the "Open in Desktop App" I can reference cells from a local spreadsheet. This will make the changes only if the local spreadsheet is open at the same time. However if I make a change to the local spreadsheet save then close and then open the SharePoint Spreadsheet with the "Desktop App" it doesn't make the changes. Is there a way for it to update while the the local Spreadsheet is closed?